# Integer hexagonal grid variations for Harborth

Tags: graph-theory, tiling

[Harborth's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harborth's_conjecture) states that every planar graph has a planar drawing in which all edge lengths are integers.  I was looking at that, and I wondered what was known about hexagonal grid graphs. For example, the following graph might be tricky.

[image: combination of 2 hex grids]

Each of those hexagons would be a hexagonal grid graph.  My question is how much variety is possible for an infinite hexagonal grid? I can only think of two classes:

1. Identical integer triangles, all neighboring triangles with edge rotation.
2. Rotate, Rotate, Mirror for identical triangles.  Here's the 3-4-5 triangle mirrored on 5.

[image: rotate, rotate, mirror of a triangle.]

Are there other ways to get a hexagonal grid where all edge lengths are integers?

EDIT: I've started building a database of [integer wheel graphs](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/WheelGraphsWithIntegerEdges/).

[image: an integer wheel hexagon]